# How do I split a list in an alphabetical range? I need to filter out a list with ranges "a" through "m" and ranges "n" through "z"

Tags: python, string, list

I have a main list which contains key value pairs that I would like to split into two separate lists. First half ranges A-M and second half ranges N-Z.

example of data trying to split:

```
Main_list = ['a 1', 'her 1', 'her 1', 'lately','mr 1', 'ornament 1', 
             'pleased 1', 'saturday 1', 'view 1', 'youth 1']
```

Result of data split:

```
list1 = ['a 1', 'her 1', 'her 1', 'lately','mr 1']

list2 = ['ornament 1', 'pleased 1', 'saturday 1', 'view 1', 'youth 1']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
Main_list = ['a 1', 'her 1', 'her 1', 'lately','mr 1', 'ornament 1', 
             'november 3', 'pleased 1', 'saturday 1', 'view 1', 'youth 1']
list1,list2 = [],[]
for i in Main_list:
    if i[0].lower() <'n':
        list1.append(i)
    else:
        list2.append(i)

print (list1)
print (list2)
```

Your output will be:

```
['a 1', 'her 1', 'her 1', 'lately', 'mr 1']
['ornament 1', 'november 3', 'pleased 1', 'saturday 1', 'view 1', 'youth 1']
```

I want to caution you about this solution. If the first char in the string is not an alphabet (is a numeric or non alphabet character), then the list will have wrong values. Let me know if you want me to address that as well

Comment: You are not accounting for the case where "n" is not in the list, Marcelo should keep that in mind

Comment: @Axel What do you mean? It's using `<` comparison, not `==`.

Comment: @Alex, see updated answer. I have added a string with n as well

Comment: ah word well i found out a new python trick today haha

Comment: If you want to make it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself): `L = list1 if i[0].lower() < 'n' else list2; L.append(i)`

Comment: Yeah. I was going to try to give that as the answer. Was not sure if OP will understand so made it a simple if else. Your statement would be the pythonic way to do it

Comment: Appreciate the help, worked exactly as i wanted it to on a bigger list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ord()` and `chr()` to generate list from `a` to `m` and use them in list comprehension as:

```
Main_list = ['a 1', 'her 1', 'her 1', 'lately','mr 1', 'ornament 1', 
             'pleased 1', 'saturday 1', 'view 1', 'youth 1']

a_to_m_chars = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('n'))]
list1 = [elt for elt in Main_list if elt[0].lower() in a_to_m_chars]
list2 = [elt for elt in Main_list if elt[0].lower() not in a_to_m_chars]
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

---

Update: You don't need to create a new list but can do conditionally in list comprehension itself as:

```
list1 = [elt for elt in Main_list if elt[0].lower() >= 'a' and elt[0].lower() <= 'm']
list2 = [elt for elt in Main_list if elt[0].lower() >= 'n' and elt[0].lower() <= 'z']
```

Comment: you need to be careful with this. if the string has upper case, you will get dinged

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the list based on first character's `ord`

```
>>> list(filter(lambda entry :  ord('a') <= ord(entry.lower()[0]) <= ord('m'), l))
['a 1', 'her 1', 'her 1', 'lately 1', 'mr 1']

>>> list(filter(lambda entry :  ord('n') <= ord(entry.lower()[0]) <= ord('z'), l))
['ornament 1', 'pleased 1', 'saturday 1', 'view 1', 'youth 1']
```

Comment: `list(filter(lambda))` is ugly, no offense. Use a list comprehension instead. Also, [`l` is a bad variable name since it looks like `1` and `I`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid); you could use `L` instead. `[x for x in L if ord('a') <= ord(x.lower()[0]) <= ord('m')]`

Comment: Oh actually, you don't even need to use `ord()`! `[x for x in L if 'a' <= x.lower()[0] <= 'm']`